# Editing GridView Not Working After Filter

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, filter

I have a dynamically templated gridview.

It allows editing, deleting, and inserting new data into the table.

I also implement another function that will to allow filtering the gridview.

Currently I can do the filtering very well. However, when entering the editing mode, the gridview is somehow reset to **"state before filtered".**

> Ex: Gridview orginally has 100 rows. After filtered only 10 rows. Enter editing mode than it will display 100 rows again.

Here is the snippet while my gridview enter the editing mode.

```
 public void GridView_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        ((TemplateField)GridView.Columns[1]).EditItemTemplate = null;
        GridView.DataBind();
        Session["SelecetedRowIndex"] = e.NewEditIndex;
    }
```

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: How are you filtering?  Are you using the "Filter Expression" property of an `SQLDataSource`? Or something else entirely?

Comment: Nope.. I created a textbox and a button. Button click trigger the event. Everything is hardcoded..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the call to `DataBind()` in your `RowEditing` method.

```
public void GridView_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    ((TemplateField)GridView.Columns[1]).EditItemTemplate = null;
    Session["SelecetedRowIndex"] = e.NewEditIndex;
}
```

By calling `DataBind()` here you're reverting the grid to its original data source, thereby losing the filtering you've previously applied.

**EDIT**

Have you tried re-applying your filter before your `RowEditing` method ends?

Comment: U know what that is a great idea.. I think that is it.. Thanks :)